# Writing a cookie for a specific domain, localhost debugging is not working

Tags: java, angular, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I have a use case where I had to write a cookie upon login with a code, and for a specific domain, lets say domain is "uat.example.com".

This will be written bya backend API after validating users authenticity, then the application calls on the domain uat.example.com/* will use this cookie read the code and use the code which is a special use case for us.

Now the problem is, our front end team's development is stuck as they use localhost:4200 on their local machine and point localhost:4200 to uat.example.com/context in order to point to this specific env, but since cookie is written for a specific domain calls from localhost:4200 are failing which earlier used to work as there was no cookie logic.
What can we do in cookie  to enable front debugging.

Answer (score 1):

On this case, I believe you have to write 2 separate cookies [one for the hosted url and another for the localhost]. I don't think there is a way to write a singular cookie for both the url's.

In your deployment pipeline / yaml file, you can restrict the deployment of localhost specific cookie.

Comment: Tried this but it didn't work.